# Joining multiple tables using xquery

Tags: xml, join, xquery

I am trying to find the name of an employee who lives in Lincoln and works in Omaha which is supposed to be 3 employees i.e. {Brady, Dan L} {Clemson Ann M} and {Gill, Mary L}. But the xQuery that I have is giving me multiple occurrences of these names. This is what I have so far:

```
for $e in doc("A8.xml")/empdata/contents/employee,
    $w in doc("A8.xml")/empdata/contents/works,
    $c in doc("A8.xml")/empdata/contents/company
where $e/city="Lincoln"
    and $c/city="Omaha"
    and $w/company_name=$c/company_name
return $e/employee_name
```

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<empdata>
    <contents>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Anderson, Susan L</employee_name> 
            <street>108th</street> 
            <city>Omaha</city> 
            <gender>F</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Brady, Dan L</employee_name> 
            <street>P street</street> 
            <city>Lincoln</city> 
            <gender>M</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Chen, Peter K</employee_name> 
            <street>124th</street> 
            <city>Omaha</city> 
            <gender>M</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Clemson, Ann M</employee_name> 
            <street>O</street> 
            <city>Lincoln</city> 
            <gender>F</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Dale, Mary K</employee_name> 
            <street>132th</street> 
            <city>Omaha</city> 
            <gender>F</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Gill, Mary L</employee_name> 
            <street>P Street</street> 
            <city>Lincoln</city> 
            <gender>F</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Harrison, Susan M</employee_name> 
            <street>Old Mill</street> 
            <city>Omaha</city> 
            <gender>F</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Jackson, Kim A</employee_name> 
            <street>178th</street> 
            <city>Omaha</city> 
            <gender>F</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Jason, Pat M</employee_name> 
            <street>8th</street> 
            <city>C.Bluffs</city> 
            <gender>M</gender>
        </employee>
        <employee>
            <employee_name>Kumar, Paul T</employee_name> 
            <street>Dodge</street> 
            <city>Omaha</city> 
            <gender>M</gender>
        </employee>
    </contents>
    <contents>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Anderson, Susan L</employee_name>
            <company_name>Mutual of Omaha</company_name>
            <salary>48000</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Brady, Dan L</employee_name>
            <company_name>FDR</company_name>
            <salary>42000</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Chen, Peter K</employee_name>
            <company_name>FDR</company_name>
            <salary>53000</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Clemson, Ann K</employee_name>
            <company_name>First Bank</company_name>
            <salary>39000</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Dale, Mary K</employee_name>
            <company_name>Mutual of Omaha</company_name>
            <salary>58000</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Gill, Mary L</employee_name>
            <company_name>Lincoln</company_name>
            <salary>48700</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Harrison, Susan M</employee_name>
            <company_name>Union Pacific</company_name>
            <salary>54320</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Jackson, Kim A</employee_name>
            <company_name>FDR</company_name>
            <salary>68000</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Jason, Pat M</employee_name>
            <company_name>FDR</company_name>
            <salary>83000</salary>
        </works>
        <works>
            <employee_name>Kumar, Paul T</employee_name>
            <company_name>FDR</company_name>
            <salary>44000</salary>
        </works>
    </contents>
    <contents>
        <company>
            <company_name>First Bank</company_name>
            <city>Omaha</city>
        </company>
        <company>
            <company_name>FDR</company_name>
            <city>Omaha</city>
        </company>
        <company>
            <company_name>Lincoln Star</company_name>
            <city>Lincoln</city>
        </company>
        <company>
            <company_name>Mutual of Omaha</company_name>
            <city>Omaha</city>
        </company>
        <company>
            <company_name>Union Pacific (UP)</company_name>
            <city>Omaha</city>
        </company>
    </contents>
</empdata>
```

Could somebody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is only one employee in the data you show who lives in Lincoln and works in Omaha, namely `"Brady, Dan L"`. `"Clemson, Ann M"` has no `works` record at all, and `"Gill, Mary L"` works for a company called `"Lincoln"`, which has no `company` record.

The problem with your query is that you do not check if the `works` element in `$w` is for the `employee` `$e`, you have to add the condition `and $e/employee_name = $w/employee_name`. Otherwise you get results for every inhabitant of Lincoln, paired with every position with an employer in Omaha.

Here is an alternative formulation of your query that might make the connection between the three parts more obvious:

```
for $emp in doc("A8.xml")/empdata/contents/employee
let $e_name := $emp/employee_name/string()
let $employers :=
    for $employment in doc("A8.xml")/empdata/contents/works[employee_name = $e_name]
    let $c_name := $employment/company_name
    return doc("A8.xml")/empdata/contents/company[company_name = $c_name]
where $emp/city = 'Lincoln' and $employers/city = 'Omaha'
return $emp
```